# Two timers to produce the same frequency but one of them is Looped 67 times

Tags: c

Pulse generation

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h> 

int main(void)
{
  DDRB = 0xFF;  
  ICR1 = 3124;// set the 5Hz frequency at the output
  TCCR1A |=( 1 <<WGM12);//set timer to CTC mode
  TCCR1B |=( 1 << CS12)|( 1 << CS10);//set prescaler to 1024

  sei();// set interrupt

  while(1)
  {
  }
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
  //Action to be done over 200ms

  TCCR2A = 0x63; // 0110 0011
  TCCR2B = 0x08 | 6; // Prescale=256

  OCR2A = 185-1; // TOP 
  OCR2B = (int) (OCR2A * 0.5);  
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT); // OC2a
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT); // OC2b   
}
```

[image]

I am using AVR Atmega328P, I would like to create a PWM pulse signal with two 5Hz frequencies generated from one Timer1, that will generate different duty cycles such that one of the frequencies has to be looped 67 times in one cycle of the other frequency. I have attached an image of how I'd like the pulses to look like on the oscilloscope. Would you please help me.

Comment: From the picture it seems that one of them is not 5 Hz. Not exactly clear your intentions for me. Like if you would want a 5 Hz and a 5 * 67 = 335 Hz signal so your second signal would cycle 67 times whille the 5 Hz doing one cycle.

Comment: why does the drawing say 5Hz, do you mean 0.2 seconds?

Comment: @user253751: I think you're right; and OP wants 5 Hz and 335 Hz.

Comment: I want to achieve 1 full cycle of 5Hz after the 335Hz being looped 67 times,Yes 5Hz is 0.2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 5 Hz and 335 Hz ("67 * 5 Hz") using a single timer, then you'd want to set the timer to the highest frequency and then have a divider in software (in the IRQ handler) to get the lower frequency.

However, for perfect square waves you want an IRQ for "rising edge" and another IRQ for "falling edge", so you'd want the timer's frequency to be double the highest frequency (e.g. 670 Hz, not 335 Hz).

For example, maybe something like:

```
 ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
 {
      static counter1 = 1;
      static counter2 = 1;

      // Actions to be done 670 times per second

      counter1--;
      if(counter1 == 0) {
           // Set output1 to "high"
           counter1 = 134;             // 670 Hz / 134 = 5 Hz
      } else if(counter1 == 67) {
           // Set output1 to "low"
      }

      counter2--;
      if(counter2 == 0) {
           // Set output2 to "high"
           counter2 = 2;               // 670 Hz / 2 = 335 Hz
      } else if(counter2 == 1) {
           // Set output2 to "low"
      }
 }
```